# How to solve $yy'' + (y')^2 = (y')^3$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following differential equation

$$yy'' + (y')^2 = (y')^3.$$

But I don't understand how should I do it. At first, I thought that I should let 
$$u=y'$$

But the solution is

$$Cy^2 − x + y = D$$

And I can't understand how to solve it.
Thanks.

Comment: $y_{1} = x$ satisfies the ODE, then look for another solution of the form $y_{2} = xv(x)$

Answer (score 2):

(You may see this as another form of Dr. Sonnhard Grauber's answer.)

Define $u$ as: $$u:=y'=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$$

You can see: $$y''=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}y}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\color{red}{u\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}y}}$$

Substituting these into the equation gets:
$$yu\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}y}+u^2=u^3$$
or equally:
$$y\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}y}+u=u^2\\\implies \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y}=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2-u}$$

You can now integrate bothsides and find $u$ as a function of $y$. After that, by substituting $u$ back with $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$, you'll end up with a simple (separable) first order equation involving $x%$ and $y$.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

To obtain a direct solution, mimicing the other answers, transform the equation to be composed of integrable terms as
$$
\frac{y''}{y'^2-y'}=\frac{y'}{y}
$$
where we need to exclude the points in the state space were $y=0$ or $y'=0$ or $y'=1$. All three cases provide solution classes, $y=c$, $y=x+c$.

Integrating gives
$$
\ln|y'-1|-\ln|y'|=\ln|y|+c
$$
or with $C=\pm e^c$
$$
1-\frac1{y'}=Cy\implies x=y-\frac C2 y^2+D
$$
etc.

Answer (score 0):

let $$u(y)=\frac{dy(x)}{dx}$$ then we have $$u(y)^2+yu'(y)u(y)=u(y)^3$$
factorizing
$$u(y)\left(-y\frac{du(y)}{dy}+u(y)^2-u(y)\right)=0$$
you must solve $$u(y)=0$$ or
$$-y\frac{du(y)}{dy}+u(y)^2-u(y)=0$$
this Can be written as
$$\frac{\frac{du(y)}{dy}}{u(y)^2-u(y)}=\frac{1}{y}$$
Can you finish?

Comment: Well, I have a problem with $(u(y)^2-u(y))dy = ydu(y)$ Now to solve the integral I have $\int(1/(u(y)^2-u(y)))du$ and isn't the solution of it using ln?

Comment: yes it is, it Can factorized into $$u(u-1)$$

Comment: should i post you the solution of this integral?

Comment: It would be great and thank you.

Comment: it is $$\ln(u-1)-\ln(u)$$

Comment: And how to lose $ln$ when I need to substitute $u$ with $y'$, what should I do?

Comment: yes that is exactly what i meant

Comment: integrating both sides we have $$\ln\left(\frac{u-1}{u}\right)=\ln(y)+C$$

Answer (score 0):

First, rewrite your ODE as

$$y'' = \dfrac{(y')^3-(y')^2}{y}=f(y,y').$$

This type of ODE can be solved by the following substitution

$$y'(x)=v(y(x)) \implies y''(x)=\dfrac{dv(y)}{dy}\dfrac{dy(x)}{dx}=v'(y)y'(x)=v'(y)v(y)$$

By applying this substitution for the ODE we obtain

$$v'v=\dfrac{v^3-v^2}{y} \implies v'(y)=\dfrac{v^2(y)-v(y)}{y},$$

which is separable.

You will also need to exclude the cases $y\equiv 0$ and $y' \equiv 0$ separately, which are trivial solutions to the ODE.

Answer (score 0):

$$yy'' + (y')^2 = (y')^3$$
$$y''y=(y')^3-(y')^2$$
$$ydy'=((y')^2-(y'))\frac {dy}{dx}dx$$
$$\frac {dy'}{((y')^2-(y'))}=\frac {dy}{y}$$
Simply integrate now
$$\int \frac {dy'}{y'(y'-1)}=\int \frac {dy}{y}=\ln|y|+K$$
$$......$$

Another simple way is to consider the derivative of $y'y$
$$yy'' + (y')^2 = (y')^3$$
$$(y'y)' = \frac {(y'y)^3}{y^3}$$
$$-\frac {(y'y)'}{(y'y)^2} = -\frac {y'}{y^2}$$
Integrate to get
$$\frac {1}{(y'y)} =\frac {1}{y}+K$$
$$\frac {1}{(y')} =1+Ky$$
Which is easy to solve...
$$\boxed{x' =1+Ky \to x=y+K_1y^2+K_2}$$